# What kind of array declaration is this?

Tags: c++, arrays

After solving practice question,i always look Red Coder's solution.Today i saw an array declaration that i have never seen before.
He declared array something like this

```
 char a['  '],b['  '];
```

Please let me know what is it ?

**P.S- This can be duplicate question.I actually tried searching it but could not find anything about it(possibly because i didn't know what to look for),if it is a duplicate please close the question and give me a link.**

Comment: for example integer value of space  is 32 (ascii) then `char a[' ']` == `char a[32]`

Comment: you mean it declares array of size int. @GrijeshChauhan

Comment: yes [check this](http://codepad.org/QNVCCoTI)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan , there are two spaces in the OP's question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes are a character constant.

- `' '` could be a space, which is `32` in ASCII.
- `'  '` could be an embedded TAB character which is `9` in ASCII
- `'  '` could be two spaces, which would be an implementation-defined `int` value.

In any case, you can supply any expression that is an integer type (or convertible to one) inside the `[]` of an array declaration.  So you will end up with `sizeof a` being `32`, or `9`, or implementation-defined value.

Comment: For some reason, I seem to get `sizeof(a)` as `8224`!!!! [ideone](http://ideone.com/Gqqadl)

Comment: @ArunA.S that's an expected result if you put two spaces inside the quotes. To see why, convert 8224 decimal to hex.

Comment: @MattMcNabb So can we declare integer type array like this or just character type ?

Comment: @chotabheem any type of array. Let's be clear that this is a Very Bad Idea, but it is not against the rules of the language.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Bad idea because it waste memory without any reason.Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @chotabheem , Bad idea because hard to understand and easy to make mistakes.

Comment: @ArunA.S haha true,don't know why RED CODERS use these kind of things in their codes ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks sir,it was a complete and clear-upto the mark answer.